# Way to access anonymous objects' methods

Tags: javascript

There is a website, which uses this code below to create website functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    {
        function I_WANT_TO_ACCESS_THIS_METHOD(){
            CODE HERE
        },
        SOME OTHER CODE
    }
});
```

I want to update this website with a greasemokey script, but I don't want to duplicate code already written. That's why I want to access methods that are part of such objects (in the code above it is the `I_WANT_TO_ACCESS_THIS_METHOD()`).

I'm not a JS master and I'm not sure if it is even possible, but I think that this is the right place to ask ;)

Comment: You can't access that function from outside the `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I_WANT_TO_ACCESS_THIS_METHOD()` is not a method of an object, but just a function defined inside another function. So you can't access it outside that function(the domcument ready callback function) scope.

Comment: that's what i thought, but wasn't sure. thanks for the answer